# docker compose build seems to be giving exit code 0 despite failure

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile, gnu-make

My makefile has something like this:

```
.PHONY: docker.delete docker.stop.rebuild docker.rebuild.restart

docker.build:
    BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain docker compose build && \
    touch docker.build || \
    rm -f docker.build

docker.delete:
    docker compose rm

docker.stop.rebuild:
    make -j 2 docker.build docker.stop

docker.rebuild.restart: docker.stop.rebuild docker.delete docker.start
```

My Dockerfile has this (simplified):

```
FROM erlang:26-alpine as builder-base

FROM builder-base as gateway-builder
    WORKDIR /build/servers/*****

    COPY vsn.txt /build/vsn.txt
    COPY servers/***** /build/servers/*****

    RUN mix local.hex --force && \
        mix local.rebar --force && \
        MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.update --all && \
        MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.get && \
        MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.compile

    RUN MIX_ENV=prod mix compile && \
        MIX_ENV=prod mix release *****

    RUN cp -aR _build/prod/rel/*****/ /*****/

FROM builder-base as *****-gateway
    WORKDIR /*****/bin

    COPY --from=gateway-builder /***** /*****

    ENTRYPOINT ["/*****/bin/*****", "start"]
```

This dockerfile will probably reproduce the same:

```
FROM erlang:26-alpine as builder-base

FROM builder-base as gateway-builder
    RUN exit 1

FROM builder-base as *****-gateway
    ENTRYPOINT ["/*****/bin/*****", "start"]
```

Partial output from running `make build` (this particular error is transitory but it illustrates the issue):

```
#7 [internal] load build context
#7 transferring context: 2.05MB 0.0s done
#7 DONE 0.1s

#8 [gateway-builder 2/6] COPY vsn.txt /build/vsn.txt
#8 DONE 0.3s

#9 [gateway-builder 3/6] COPY servers/***** /build/servers/*****
#9 DONE 0.1s

#10 [gateway-builder 4/6] RUN mix local.hex --force &&         mix local.rebar --force &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.update --all &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.get &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.compile
#10 1.053 ** (Mix) httpc request failed with: {:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:options, :incompatible, [verify: :verify_peer, cacerts: :undefined]}}]}
#10 1.053
#10 1.053 Could not install Hex because Mix could not download metadata at https://repo.hex.pm/installs/hex-1.x.csv.
#10 1.053
#10 1.053 Alternatively, you can compile and install Hex directly with this command:
#10 1.053
#10 1.053     mix archive.install github hexpm/hex branch latest
#10 1.053
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c mix local.hex --force &&         mix local.rebar --force &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.update --all &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.get &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.compile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [gateway-builder 4/6] RUN mix local.hex --force &&         mix local.rebar --force &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.update --all &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.get &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.compile:
#10 1.053 ** (Mix) httpc request failed with: {:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:options, :incompatible, [verify: :verify_peer, cacerts: :undefined]}}]}
#10 1.053
#10 1.053 Could not install Hex because Mix could not download metadata at https://repo.hex.pm/installs/hex-1.x.csv.
#10 1.053
#10 1.053 Alternatively, you can compile and install Hex directly with this command:
#10 1.053
#10 1.053     mix archive.install github hexpm/hex branch latest
#10 1.053
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mix local.hex --force &&         mix local.rebar --force &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.update --all &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.get &&         MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.compile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dhorkin/repos/*****/servers/*****'
[]
No stopped containers
[+] Running 6/6
 ✔ Network *****_local_close    Created                                                                               0.1s
 ✔ Container cockroach_service  Healthy                                                                              43.4s
 ✔ Container redis              Healthy                                                                              43.4s
 ✔ Container db-init            Exited                                                                               43.3s
 ✔ Container *****-gateway      Started                                                                              73.7s
```

Despite seeing build errors in the output, it still seems to run the touch command. Any idea why?

I have docker 23.0.5. I've tried with Make 4.3 and 4.4.1

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BMitch I don't think it's possible to provide a minimal reproducible example, but I've provided significantly more context above

Comment: Why do you think it ran the `touch` command?  Also, please provide the output make printed before it started the build, and what command line you used to start it.  It's not clear what commands make is actually running here.  Also FYI it's always wrong to start a sub-make with the `make` command.  You should always use the variable `$(MAKE)` instead.

Comment: Why isn't it possible to make a 2 line example Dockerfile (from busybox, run exit 1) and a 3 line Makefile to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shell programming question, not a makefile question.  When you write this in the shell:

```
command1 && command2
```

then `command2` is only invoked if `command1` does not fail.  Well, how does the shell know if `command1` failed?  Every command that is invoked provides an exit code when it stops.  If the exit code is 0, then the shell considers the command to have succeeded (and will run `command2`).  If the exit code is any other value than 0, then the shell considers the command to have failed (and will not run `command2`).

If the command `docker compose build && touch build` is running the `touch` command, it means that `docker compose build` is exiting with a success (0) exit code.  If the command you're invoking inside docker is failing then that failing exit code is not being transferred to be the exit code of the `docker compose` command.

Comment: sounds like more of a Docker issue than a shell issue. What you described is exactly what I was intending

Comment: Well, you'll have to examine what your `docker compose build` command does.  There's nothing here in your question that will let us help you.

Comment: I've provided significantly more context above